# JavaScript Regular Expression - Extract number from next to word

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Been a long time since I have touched regular expressions. It's simple but I am pulling my hair out over it.

I have a string as follows that I get from the DOM `"MIN20, MAX40"`. I want to be able to use regex in JavaScript to extract the integer next to `MIN` and the integer next to `MAX` and put into separate variables `min` and `max`. I cannot figure a way to do it.

Thanks to who ever helps me, you will be a life saver!

Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use:

```
var input   = "MIN20, MAX40";
var matches = input.match(/MIN(\d+),\s*MAX(\d+)/);
var min = matches[1];
var max = matches[2];
```

[**JSfiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/PuP3F/)

Comment: This does the job for me. Although Tim Down's example is good if needed more than two values. Thanks to you all

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Tim Down's example for future readers

Answer (score 4):

I think this would work:

```
var matches = "MIN20, MAX40".match(/MIN(\d+), MAX(\d+)/);
var min = matches[1]; 
var max = matches[2];
```

Comment: +1! Clean and simple (you could add a check for `matches` to make it even better).

Comment: If we're going this simple, there's no need for a regular expression. We could just do `var str = "MIN20, MAX40", min = str.slice(3, 5), max = str.slice(10, 12);`

Comment: or even simpler `min = 20, max = 40;` :D

Comment: copy your example to another fiddle please. Jsfiddle slow as hell.

Answer (score 2):

The following will extract numbers following "MIN" and "MAX" into arrays of integers called `mins` and `maxes`:

```
var mins = [], maxes = [], result, arr, num;
var str = "MIN20, MAX40, MIN50";

while ( (result = /(MIN|MAX)(\d+)/g.exec(str)) ) {
    arr = (result[1] == "MIN") ? mins : maxes; 
    num = parseInt(result[2]);
    arr.push(num);
}

// mins: [20, 50]
// maxes: [40]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "MIN20, MAX40";
value = str.replace(/^MIN(\d+),\sMAX(\d+)$/, function(s, min, max) {
    return [min, max]
});

console.log(value); // array
```

Comment: It doesn't result into an array. typeof value == "string" (in Google Chrome at least)

Comment: how bizarre... I tried in FF 3.6.12, anyway codaddict solution is the best

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
var str='MIN20, MAX40';

min = str.match(/MIN(\d+),/)[1];
max = str.match(/MAX(\d+)$/)[1];
```