# how to get 4 with Jquery from <div id="item 4">

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I get the number from a div `<div id="item 4">` ? I have a posts div and I add the id of each post to the item id in php like `<div id="item <?php echo $post->id; ?>">` and then I need to get it with jquery

edit: since i did not know ids are not allowed with spaces, i need to get the number from `<div id="item_4">`

Comment: IDs are not allowed to contain spaces (not that it makes any difference to the solution, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193536/javascript-regular-expression-extract-number-from-next-to-word)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery get number from id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427853/jquery-get-number-from-id)

Comment: @Asif: Not if it should be valid in HTML4 and for CSS selectors. In both cases, IDs are not allowed to start with numbers.

Comment: @FelixKling thanx. . .even i get this knowledge just now  :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, id's can't contain spaces, so instead of `item 4` your id should be `item_4`.

Then you can just do something like this:

```
var this_id = parseInt($('my_selector').attr('id').match(/_([0-9]+)$/)[1]);
```

This captures all the numbers at the end of the id (so in `item_4` it gets 4, and in `item_4_take_2` it gets 2).

Comment: Whoever -1'ed it, at least post a comment >_>

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more ease of use:

Use the div names as `item1`, `item2`, `itme3`, etc, then apply:

```
var id = $("div").attr('id').replace(/item/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

`<div id="item_<?php echo $post->id; ?>" data-postId="<?php echo $post->id; ?>"></div>`

You can then fetch the Id in jquery using:

`$('my_selector').attr('data-postId')`

Comment: Better: Use `data-*` attributes. `data-postId="..."`. This will be compatible with HTML5.