# Need to get Zip Code from An Address using Regex in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I need to extract Zip/Postal Code out of an address in javascript using Regex.

The address that i am passing currently is :

**Vittal Mallya Road, KG Halli, Sampangi Rama Nagar, Bangalore, Karnataka 560001, India**

The regex that i have formed for getting the Zip Code is :

**var Zip=results[0].formatted_address;
Zip = Zip.replace( /^\D+/g, '');**

The output that i am getting is 560001, India instead of only 560001. Also, i want to ignore any number that may come in the beginning of the address like Door Number/House/Street Number since i am only concerned with Zip Code. Moreover, it should also work in case we pass a UK/USA Address containing the respective Zip Code. Any help in this matter will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your regex in action: [regexr.com](http://regexr.com?35bc3)

```
^\D+
```

It matches **from begining of line** (^) any ***non-digit (\D)*** char,
Meaning it will start at beginning of line and end at first number, in your case it will match:

```
Vittal Mallya Road, KG Halli, Sampangi Rama Nagar, Bangalore, Karnataka
```

Then you delete this match, leaving `560001, India`

You want `\d{6}` - matches **any digit 6 times**, or 6 digits.

Then you can extract value with [Pattern and Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237068)

Comment: Hi Ruslashev, Will the Pattern and Matcher approach work with Javascripts?

Comment: Quite honestly, I am a Java and Javascript noob, but as far as my google-fu goes, [it's even simpler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4193536).

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes more sense to match the zip code, rather than match non numeric items and delete them. This pattern will match US zip codes and Canadian postal codes within an address string

(\d{5}([ -]\d{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}[ -]\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$)

https://regexr.com/455ns