# Regex to format price

Tags: javascript

I have some price tags like $23.47,-$50.00, $0.37, $113.57,$600,0456.00 and so on. I intend to remove dollar($),thousand separator(,) and also any white space.

For this purpose I am using regex as

```
(Sometext).replace(/^[, ]+|[, ]+$|[, ]+/g, "").replace('$',"").replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

Is there any better way to combine all this operations(remove thousand separator comma, remove dollar symbol, remove white space) with single replace?

Comment: `"-$12,33.00".replace(/[^\d\-\.]/g,'')`. Outputs "-1233.00"

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the regex OR operator?  Something like this:

```
(Sometext).replace(/^[, ]+|[, ]+$|[, ]+|\$|\s+/g, "");
```

The `|` represent an OR in regex.  I just placed the pipe between the three patterns you want to match, and used them within a single `replace()`. I also escaped the `$` in dollar sign matching statement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193536/javascript-regular-expression-extract-number-from-next-to-word) try:

```
var price = "$23 . 47"
var simpleValue = price.match(/(\d+)/g).join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
'$444,55,22.33'.replace(/[,\s$]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could target anything NOT what you want to keep.

So, a regex like: `price.replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, '');`

The `^` in the brackets tells it to match anything but the included characters.

The `\d` allows any numeric character.